# HTTPS connection to public IP address of home server timed out, works on local network?

Tags: networking, server, internet

- I setup CalDAV server on HomeServer (192.168.1.20).
- I can connect to and configure CalDAV server from browser on Desktop Client (192.168.1.10) on HTTP or HTTPS on port 5000 (192.168.1.20:5000 and https://192.168.1.20:5000).

  - CalDAV server should accept incoming connections from inside and **outside** the Local Network (hosts = 0.0.0.0:5000) ???
- I properly configured Router (192.168.1.1) to port forward 5000 to HomeServer.
- I looked up Public (External) IP address (111.222.333.444).
- I do not find information stating that my ISP blocks ports.
- `ping 111.222.333.444` seems to work properly from inside and **outside** the Local Network
- From inside and **outside** the Local Network, I cannot establish a connection to CalDAV server at http://111.222.333.444:5000 or https://111.222.333.444:5000.

  - The connection has timed out.

What diagnostics should I attempt to identify and solve the problem?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you enter http://192.168.1.20:5000 on your local network it works? Or do you simply type http://192.168.1.20 (without port) for it to work?

Comment: Note that it is normal to be unable to access a local resource using your home router's public IP address.  For this to work, your router would have to support hairpin NAT, which most consumer-grade routers do not.  Focus on the problem of being unable to access from outside your home via the port-forwarding you have configured.